# PHP array to javascript returning one character

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following PHP array:

```
 $array = array("picture1"=>"item1", "picture2"=>"item2",
     "picture3"=>"item3", "picture4"=>"item4");
```

I am trying to get the array values through this html code using jquery's .attr() method.

```
<td data-pictures="<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>"></td>

pictures = $(this).attr('data-pictures');
```

When I do a console log for the pictures variable, I am getting only a "{" and nothing more. Can someone help?

Comment: you may have to escape the json encoded value else it will become something like `data-pictures="{"picture1":"item1",...}"`, so as you can see the string literal is terminated before `picture1`

Answer (score 3):

Change this line

```
<td data-pictures="<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>"></td>
```

to

```
<td data-pictures="<?php echo htmlentities(json_encode($array)); ?>"></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Arun has said, quotes must be escaped first or the attribute will be terminated. You can use `htmlspecialchars()` in this case. Consider this example:

```
<?php $array = array("picture1"=>"item1", "picture2"=>"item2", "picture3"=>"item3", "picture4"=>"item4"); ?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td data-pictures="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($array)); ?>"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var pictures = $.parseJSON($('td').attr('data-pictures'));
    console.log(pictures);

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Such an easy oversight!

Answer (score 0):

This is because of mistake in using quotes. You can use :

```
<td data-pictures='<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>'></td>
```

**Note**
Change double quote with single quote